# find in mongodb based on text containing charecter /

Tags: mongodb

when i am trying to use find() in mongodb based  on a string containing / for example IBPS/State Bank, the request to get the data  is passed has /IBPS/State%20Bank  and getting the error

Cannot GET /findCategoryByName/IBPS/State%20Bank

Comment: Are you conversing with the MongoDB over a rest api or is this the endpoint for your server application

Comment: What are you doing? Are you using node.js and mongodb? if yes, how you have defined your endpoint findCategoryByName? Paste your code here

Comment: yes i am  conversing with the MongoDB over a rest api

Comment: yes  i am using node.js and mongodb router.route('/findCategoryByName/:categoryName')
 .get(function(req,res){
  Categories.find({categoryName:req.params.categoryName},function(err,books){
   if(err)
    res.send(err);
   res.send(books);
  });
 });